# JanusGraph with Elasticsearch index is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, gremlin, janusgraph

I have added mixed index in JanusGraph to support full-text search with Elasticsearch.

I have mixed index like:

```java
myindex = mgmt.buildIndex("myesindex", Vertex.class)
    .addKey("name", Mapping.TEXTSTRING.asParameter())
    .addKey("sabindex", Mapping.TEXTSTRING.asParameter())
    .buildMixedIndex("search");
```

I am able to load data into Elasticsearch engine.
Also I am able to execute the query successfully.

The issue I am facing is when I hit query :

```
g.V().has('code','abc').valueMap()
==>{str=[some text], code=[abc], sab=[sab], sabindex=[sabindex], name=[[some tex]]}
```

I am getting the result successfully, but when I try to search with name and code:

```
g.V().has('name', textContains('some text')).has('code','abc').valueMap()
```

code field is also indexed(composite)

At that time I am getting no result. Though data is present in graph and Elasticsearch.

And another scenario is same query with different name and code works successfully. I also rebuild the graph multiple times but not getting positive results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query shows the value is `name=[[some tex]]`. It is missing the final `t` in `text`, so that explains why the query isn't matching on `some text`.

If you instead do `textContains('some tex')`, you would get the same result as the first query. Using the `profile()` step would show that the `myindex` was utilized.

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/pluradj/c851224f6fd103d8e49b8403e8391dff) of the recreate scenario.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried with textContains method it works well but performance of the query is slow as compared to eq

Comment: Did you verify that the index is being utilized? If you need more specific debugging help, the janusgraph-users group may be a better forum for your questions. https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/README.md#community

Comment: Yes I checked logs of elastic engine.
Query is hiiting there.